# Getting Only The Path From Named Route in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

How can i get relative path in laravel 5.8 named route.

I use this

```
route("v3.home.image",$my_parameters)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
route($name, $parameters = [], $absolute = true)
```

Only change third argemant to `false`

```
route("v3.home.image",$my_parameters , false)
```